# Wouldn't it be smart to only use the stack and make its size really big?

Tags: c++, operating-system, stack

Putting Data on the stack seems really fast performance wise, since it has way less CPU instructions then allocating Memory on the heap. Why isn't it a smart idea (or maybe it is?) to set the stack size for my executable to many gigabytes (when enough physical Memory is available) and just store everything that normally goes to the heap, there? Is it even possible to go over the system stack limit?
Of course I am not talking about setting the stack size for ALL applications that high, just for one specific one, from which I know, for example, that it needs at max 4GB of memory.

Comment: On a modern protected OS the "heap" isn't shared between processes. All processes are isolated from each other. And accessing memory on the stack or from the heap is just about the same, it's all just memory.

Comment: Well, when I look at generated Assambly from C++ Code, usually I need 6 or 7 instructions for allocating memory on the heap, but just 1 for the stack. That seems like A LOT! But edited the "share" Part, thanks!

Comment: *Well, when I look at generated Assambly from C++ Code* -- Wouldn't it be obvious that the heap memory must be managed in some way when it is asked to allocate memory?  Of course heap management is "slower" than picking an offset from the stack.

Comment: Yes, of course that is obvious, I wasn't fighting that. My question still stands. Why not just use the stack, if picking an offset is faster.

Comment: A huge stack will run into problems if you use multiple threads, and these use 4GB stack each.

Comment: Well, that's measurable, isn't it? Let's say, I use 4 threads, then I could set the stacksize to 1GB. Edit: on further thought, a problem could be, that it's not dynamic enough, since one thread could need 3GB, and another one just 500MB. So this would be a problem!

Comment: Unless you allocate and reallocate in a tight loop, the heap allocation overhead will be negligible when compared to the whole run-time of the program. Access to the memory will still be the same once it's allocated. The savings you think you will be getting will not be measurable. And it will waste a *lot* of space for programs that use little stack and not too much heap. Generally, the programs themselves have much better idea of how much memory they need than the compiler can deduce.

Comment: the entire question is pointless, if you preallocate the entire 4GBs of RAM on the stack, then you will have to manage that memory yourself and chop it to small pieces, which is basically reimplementing the OS's malloc, which is never going to beat the OS's malloc unless you know **EXACTLY** how much memory you are going to need at the start of the program, in which case allocating those 4GBs on the heap does the same thing, i can see one or two scenarios where this could work, but it is not needed in 99.9% of programs.

Comment: Either I didn't get your point or you didn't understand my question fully. I wasn't talking about pre-allocating (I think?). Edit: thought about it and I think I understand, what you want to tell me. Of course you are right. Thanks!

Comment: @debaser36 that's what makes it sort of pointless, you can't just "allocate" memory on the stack, you allocate memory only for your stack frame, and have to release it when you exit the function, so you use the heap if you need to allocate memory that will outlive your function ..... unless you preallocate that memory on the stack, so to substitute the heap for the stack you need to know how much memory you are going to need ahead of time ..... and there are already heap arenas that you can use if you do know the memory you are going to need.

Comment: You can program quite a bit with just *automatic storage* (q.v. [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)).  The only reason **not** to use automatic storage is if you need to manage the object lifespan manually (i.e., *dynamic storage*) — for something that needs to continue to exist outside of a scope.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is very simple: the heap has to be able to handle arbitrary allocations and deallocations in an order.  So it has to be able to cope with things like:

```
allocate a
allocate b
allocate c
free b
allocate d
free a
and so on
```

The stack, on the other hand, has a much easier job to do.  It only ever has to do this:

```
allocate a
allocate b
allocate c
free c
allocate d
free d
free b
free a
```

See the difference?  Unlike the heap, the stack only ever has to free the most recent allocation.  This means that all it needs to keep track of is the current 'high water mark'.   When memory is allocated, that will be incremented.  When that memory is freed, it will be decremented.

The heap, on the other hand, needs to use much more complex algorithms to manage memory efficiently, and that's where the extra time goes.  You could read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/The-GNU-Allocator.html) to get a quick overview of how glibc goes about it, and there are further links in there if you want to study this in more depth.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the design of your application. If you design utilizing `new-delete` calls over and over in loops, then yo will pay the performance cost of such design. This is why you have to be careful regarding memory allocation/de-allocation design of your application.

`stack` is supposed to keep local variables, return address (callee address), and `this` pointer (when you have classes), as such, there would be no need to dramatically increase its size. If you design to have a large stack and use its memory as a pool for your custom `alloc-free`, then it would be fine (even though unnecessary, because you can call once memory allocation large enough for later custom allocation), your final image file would be large.

I think your OS has to check out if you have already passed the stack limitation or not, occasionally and for putting many variables on stack, it makes your process slow (not sure about this!).

Answer (score 0):

The stack is generally used to keep track of the `call stack` and other `local variables`. Once the stack grows out of bounds, it's almost always a *design flaw*.

Taking that into consideration, having a limited stack size is a very important mechanism to prevent someone from doing a whole bunch of allocations (indefinitely) with infinite recursion for example.

This would only be caught after some time (depending on the stack size you set) and in the process slow down and exhaust processes running on the OS. I don't think blindly resizing the stack makes sense for that reason.

Comment: Wow, that makes sense (it being a security check). Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), I'll give a concrete example in C++ of something you *need* dynamic allocation for: storing user input.

Consider this small piece of code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> group_a;
    std::vector<int> group_b;

    while (true) {
        int group;
        int n;
        std::cin << group << n;
        if (group == 1) {
            group_a.push_back(n);
        } else {
            group_b.push_back(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Assume proper user input (or additional checking code). If you were to use static allocation for everything, you would need to either reserve sufficient space for both vectors (basically replace them with `std::array`s), or move all of `group_b` as well as other variables (`group` and `n`) in memory every time you add to `group_a`.

It turns out that, in actual programs that do useful things, much more complex versions of this scenario occur frequently, and not just with user input. The only way to solve this efficiently is to use dynamic allocations.

Note that I have only talked about static and dynamic allocations and I have yet to mention the stack and the heap. That's simply because the stack is an efficient structure for dealing with static allocation and the heap for dealing with dynamic allocation. You certainly could implement dynamic allocation on the stack, but it would be wasteful (you need to reserve enough space) and no more efficient than on the heap. Instead, we let the operating system handle the system's memory for us. As for implementing static allocation on the heap, that's just `std::stack`.